# uninstall eclipse 3.5

Tags: eclipse

i'm having problems with eclipse and i think i need to re-install it. is there a safe/recommended way to uninstall it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have Eclipse 3.6.2 (Helios) and when I have to uninstall it, the extent of this operation is moving the folder into the recycle bin.  Just be sure that your workspaces aren't saved inside (or if they are, move them out), and you should be set.

Answer (score 13):

There's no installer for Eclipse (the one from eclipse.org) , so just delete your Eclipse folder.

However, there's 2 other parts to Eclipse that can cause trouble if they are damaged.

- your workspace, usually just a folder called "Workspace" in your user home folder.
- a folder named ".eclipse" in your user home folder.

Rename those and see if it helps (better not delete them, as they contain your projects and setttings)

Comment: Are you sure about the .eclipse directory? I don't have one.

Comment: I recently installed Eclipse. (This involved copying it into a Program Files folder in Windows.) It created one of these .eclipse directories in my user's home directory. The installation didn't work properly, so I had to delete both the "eclipse" folder and the ".eclipse" one. Since then, it doesn't seem to create the ".eclipse" folder anymore. I've found it's quite a difficult program when it comes to installation and uninstallation of it and its plug-ins.

Answer (score 4):

Just delete it. It don't "install" itself in the normal way, it's just a (very big) unzipped file.

You may also want to delete the `.metadata` directories, wherever you created workspaces, but that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Deleting `.metadata` directories in project folders is however recommended, for the case the messup was caused by bad settings/plugins (or was that what you *actually* meant? ;) )

Comment: To be clear, there are not multiple .metadata directories in multiple places so don't go looking for them.  There is one .metadata directory.

Answer (score 4):

Open eclipse

1. Click Help > About and then click  command link Installation
   Details... to open a dialog showing pages that provide more detail
   about your installation.
2. Click the Installed Software tab to see a list of the software
   items that you have installed into your system.
3. Select the items that you wish to uninstall.
4. Click Uninstall....
5. The Uninstall Details page will show you a list of the items that
   will be uninstalled. Expanding each item will show what additional
   items (if any) will be uninstalled as a result of your choice.
6. If you change your mind about which items should be uninstalled,
   you may click Back to see a checkmark list of the items you selected
   before. You may check and uncheck different items in the list, and
   click Next when you are ready to continue.
7. Click Finish to start the uninstall.
8. Once all of the software is uninstalled successfully, you will be
   prompted to restart for the Workbench. Click Yes when asked to exit
   and restart the Workbench for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to delete the eclipse installation folder. Nothing is "installed" by Eclipse into your system apart from this folder.

But I don't think you really need to delete it completely from your file system. Maybe you can give us a more detailed description of your issue for us to be able to point you to an efficient solution. Maybe you only have to restart from a clean workspace or revert the Eclipse installation to a previous state.

Anyway if you really want to delete it, pay attention to backup your workspace in case you chose to store it in the Eclipse installation folder.

Comment: hi thanks for that. I can't create a new project as eclipse can't find proguard.cfg. because of this there is no R.java file created. I've searched for a solution but nobody seems to have answer. I just thought it would be easier to start again with fresh installation.